# How to revert uncommitted changes to files of a certain type in git

Tags: git, git-revert

I have a bunch of modified files in my git repository and a large number of them are xml files. How do I revert changes (reset modifications) of only the xml files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you all for your replies, but I have found, for me, most accurate solution:

```
git diff --name-only -- '*.xml' | sed 's, ,\\&,g' | xargs git checkout --
```

sed is user to escape spaces which troubled xargs and everything is working very fast and accurate.

Comment: see my answer, you don't need all of this :)

Comment: How to do reverse, with simple and short changes to your code, i.e. how to restore only all modified files that doesn't match *.xml or better yet doesn't match *.xml and *.php ??

Answer (score 69):

You don't need `find` or `sed`, you can use wildcards as git understands them (doesn't depend on your shell):

```
git checkout -- "*.xml"
```

The quotes will prevent your shell to expand the command to only files in the current directory before its execution.

You can also disable shell glob expansion (with bash) :

```
set -f
git checkout -- *.xml
```

This, of course, will irremediably erase your changes!

Comment: `*/*.xml` is not "xml files in all directories" either.

Comment: @wRAR found it... globbing in git isn't very well documented

Comment: `**/*.xml` will use your shell globs, so files deleted won't be checked out, but if it's changes only, that should work.

Comment: Actually it doesn't uses shell globs, but git understands globs (I checked by disabling shell glob expansion with `set -f` in bash), and it works also for restoring deleted files

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't work when I specify a branch :-( `git checkout master -- "*.xml"` for example doesn't work where `git checkout -- "*.xml"` does :-(

Comment: @mjaggard cuz branch goes in place of `--`, i.e. `git checkout master "*.xml"`

Comment: @mjaggard When you specify branch then behavior is indeed different. It doesn't takes files recursively :/. You can look at my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53952571/350384) to see how to do it differently.

Comment: Is there a way to checkout -- files that are not a certain type? like git checkout -- "!*.xml"

Comment: Is there something like _--dry-run_ for merge to **simulate** this before actually doing it, to see which files would be checked out?

Comment: @CharlesB How to do reverse, with simple and short changes to your code, i.e. how to restore only all modified files that doesn't match *.xml or better yet doesn't match *.xml and *.php ??

Comment: @VickyDev `git checkout -- ':!*.xml'` 
For not matching xml and php I'm not sure

Comment: @CharlesB .php is also a type of text file like .xml, so in nutshell I am just asking on **how to do this for not matching multiple extensions** ?

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name '*.xml' -print0 | xargs -0 git checkout HEAD
```

or something equivalent if your system doesn't have `find` and `xargs`. Or just `git checkout HEAD **/*.xml` in `zsh` or any other shell with this form of reqursive globbing.