# git checkout only certain file types for entire project

Tags: git

Is there a way to perform a git checkout for only certain file types (.xlf), which recurses down through the entire repository? The results should contain the struture of the repository, meaning the folders, and the contained files of a certain extension.

**Repo A**

```
file.xlf
file.txt
level2/
    file2.xlf
    file2.txt
    level3/
        file3.xlf
        file3.txt
```

After checkout repo B looks like:

**Repo B**

```
file.xlf
    /level2
    file2.xlf
        /level3
        file3.xlf
```

This is what I have so far:

```
$ git checkout FETCH_HEAD -- '*.xlf'
```

This gives all of the `".xlf"` files at the root level, but is not recursive down to subdirectories.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Check [Dadaso's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31265680/git-checkout-only-certain-file-types-for-entire-project/#44957542) for a solution that will work in most of cases.

You can try something like this, using `git ls-tree` and `grep`:

```
git checkout origin/master -- `git ls-tree origin/master -r --name-only | grep ".xlf"`
```

Note this expects a remote `origin` in a `master` branch. Also you must provide the right filter/extension to `grep`.

> Before this command, you should have done something like this:

```
git init
git remote add origin <project.git>
git fetch
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem. One thing to note, as it happened to me, is if there is a typo in the file extension, git squawks about a "Detached Head". If the file extension is found, then this message does not occur.

Answer (score 32):

**You don't need find or sed, you can use wildcards as git understands them (doesn't depend on your shell):**

```
git checkout -- "*.xml"
```

**The quotes will prevent your shell to expand the command to only files in the current directory before its execution.**

You can also disable shell glob expansion (with bash) :

```
set -f
git checkout -- *.xml
```

This, of course, will irremediably erase your changes!

Comment: This is most definitely the cleanest solution.

Comment: How to match everything _except_ a specific type of file?

Comment: This works recursively? It doesn't on Windows, at least.

Comment: @aoetalks For me it works recursively. But only the `git checkout -- "*.xml"` version (checking out from index) the `git checkout HEAD -- "*.xml"` (checkoing out from branch name) looks like doesn't work recursively.

Comment: `git checkout HEAD -- **/*.xml` is how you could have it recursively go thru the current directories folders and then checkout all the .xmls in those folders. if there's more folders within those folders, unfortunately have to chain it like this `**/**/*.xml` and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Dadaso's answer `git checkout -- "*.xml"` checks out all .xml files **recursively** from index to working directory.

However for some reasons `git checkout branch-name -- "*.xml"` (checking out files from `branch-name` branch) **doesn't work recursively** and only checks "xml" files in root directory.

So IMO the best is to use `git ls-tree` then filter file names you are interested in and pass it to `git checkout branch-name --`. Here are the commands you can use:

- Bash (and git bash on windows) version:

  ```
  git ls-tree branch-name --full-tree --name-only -r | grep "\.xml" | xargs git checkout branch-name --
  ```
- cmd (windows) version (if you don't have "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin" in you PATH):

  ```
  git ls-tree branch-name --full-tree --name-only -r | "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\grep.exe" "\.xml" | "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\xargs.exe" git checkout branch-name --
  ```
- for powershell it's still better to call `cmd.exe` because it's much faster (powershell doesn't have good support for native stdin/stdout pipelining):

  ```
  cmd.exe /C 'git ls-tree branch-name --full-tree --name-only -r | "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\grep.exe" "\.xml" | "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\xargs.exe" git checkout branch-name --'
  ```
- However you you have small number of files you can try this in powershell (like in @aoetalks answer). But I found it extremely slow for couple of houndeds files:

  ```
  git ls-tree branch-name --full-tree --name-only -r | sls "\.xml" | %{ git checkout branch-name -- $_ }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

On PowerShell (Windows, haven't tried PowerShell Core+Linux), I was able to do it like this

`git ls-tree master -r --name-only | sls ".cscfg" | foreach { git checkout origin/master -- $_ }`

Comment: This one finally worked for me because my directories have spaces in them. I just had to put "" around the $_ part.

Answer (score 0):

No; git operates at a whole-repository (and whole-history) level; there's no way of getting a partial checkout of a repository. You can of course check out the repository and then delete everything that doesn't match your file, but of course you gain virtually nothing by doing so.

Comment: Per-blob clone is now a thing BTW: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository/52269934#52269934 :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had troubles with the solutions provided, and here is my solution

1. checkout all change from the other branch `git checkout branch -- ./`
2. only stage the certain type `git add \*.type`
3. commit staged files `git commit`
4. reset the other files `git reset --hard`