# How to revert committed changes to files of a certain type in git

Tags: git

I would like to revert an older git known commit (not the last one, already pushed to upstream), but would like to affect only certain file types, e.g. `*.java`. Other changes, such as changes to files of type `*.xml` I would like to keep.

Any downstream changes to `*.java` files should be undone as well.

Comment: Are you looking to revert the changes in `*.java` from only the last commit?

Comment: If there are subsequent commits in that file, do you want preserve those?

Comment: See updated [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63719841/11057988)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the `commitid` you want to revert from, you could checkout the known files from the parent commit (`commitid^`). In your case the files are `*.java`:

```
# checkout *.java files recursively from a parent commit of a known "commitid"
git checkout commitid^ -- `git ls-tree commitid -r --name-only | grep ".java"`

# Commit
git commit
```

A parent commit is denoted by a caret (`^`) symbol after the commit hash.

Also see similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2734035/11057988). Also see checkout by [wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31310644/11057988).

Answer (score 2):

```
# first revert your commit but without committing
git revert -n <commitToRevert>

# then restore your .xml files
git checkout <commitToRevert> -- *.xml

# and finally commit
git commit
```

([revert without committing](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert#Documentation/git-revert.txt---no-commit))