# Git reset all files with particular extension

Tags: git, github, git-reset

I have changes in many types of file like `.tsx` `.scss` and `.scss.d.ts`, and have committed and pushed to my branch.

Is there any way I can reset only extension `.scss.d.ts` with master ?

Keep the changes in `.tsx` and `.scss` only reset `.scss.d.ts` with master.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to revert uncommitted changes to files of a certain type in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864655/how-to-revert-uncommitted-changes-to-files-of-a-certain-type-in-git)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could first output a list of the paths with

```
git ls-files master -- *.scss.d.ts
```

then that list can be send to the `checkout` command* to restore each of them to their state on `master`

```
git checkout master -- $(git ls-files master -- *.scss.d.ts)
```

* Note that since recent git versions, you also have [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) to the same effect

```
git restore --source=master '*.scss.d.ts'
```

Comment: am able to get liest but second command does not work for me.

Comment: yeah files have been committed and pushed to branch. :(

Comment: @antikd "files have been committed and pushed to branch." You seem to imply that's a bad thing. Why? Also, what "does not work"? Do you get an error? An unexpected state for your files?

Comment: `git checkout master -- $(git ls-files -- *.scss.d.ts)` gives these error
error: pathspec 'pathtofile.scss.d.ts' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Comment: This error is coming for 8 files and all of them does exist.

Comment: Aww.... sorry, I made a stupid copy-pasting mistake when reformatting my answer, but of course `master` has to be referenced in the call to `ls-files` too (`git checkout master -- $(git ls-files master -- *.scss.d.ts)`), I edited.

Comment: FYI am running this on git bash on windows 10.

Comment: @ankitd Same environment here, I tried it on a repo and it worked. I wonder what could be different in your case...

Comment: While this works, it's overly complex and probably not what most people are looking for.  Sorry, but there are better ways to do this.

Comment: FYI the `checkout branch --` version does a hard reset whereas the `restore` only does a soft reset.

Answer (score 15):

```
git reset master -- "*.scss.d.ts"
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: On `git version 2.32.0 (Apple Git-132)`, simply
   **`git reset "*.scss.d.ts"`**
seems to work as well.

Comment: @MTS No, I'm afraid this is a confusion. OP wanted to *get rid* of changes, not keep and unstage them. This command does **not** achieve the goal, it only *unstages* files with a particular extension. See my solution for a maybe slightly more complex, but working solution.

Comment: @RomainValeri where does OP say “rid”? All I see is “reset”.

Comment: @MTS that will reset to HEAD, which may be different from master (which is what OP requested).

Comment: @MTS First, it sounded more like the colloquial use of "reset", not the specific git meaning, but then the mention of "keep the changes in ..." convinced me it clearly wasn't "resetting understood as unstaging" from OP. We'd need them to clarify here, I guess.